# What's the best practice for storing a large static array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I want to store a large array of countries in my angular app as there are large forms that sometime require a country select. I have the following ideas but have no idea what is the best practice:

1. Store the array in a data service and grab when required
2. Store the array as a property on the component
3. Store the array in a file of static variables and grab when required

EDIT: I just want to add that this array will be used in a re-usable select component that can be used many times over when building the forms.

Comment: other viable option: store in a data service, grab when required and also cache in local/session storage

Comment: I would store it in a data service and grab from there. This allows you to use it in multiple components (if required) easily.

Comment: If there is no state involved, #3 seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: If there is only ~200 countries then this array is far from being large :) I would store it in dataservice.

Comment: "Large array of countries": from a performance standpoint, even an array of every single country on the planet is not "large". Our app regularly generates rich lists of thousands of elements.

Comment: @Alex thanks this is what i went with but do not need to store in local storage

Comment: @TSR thanks this is what i went with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Store the array in a data service and grab when required

It is the best one, as a service in Angular behaves basically like a singleton. It'll persist throughout the program lifecycle.

You can even make it better by implementing a getter-setter kind of interface.

```
get countries(): Country[] {
  // If present in Local Storage, return that
  // Else return whatever is there in memory
  // Else fetch from network, i.e. httpClient.get()
}

set countries(countries: Country[]) {
  // Store the countries in memory
  // Store the countries in the Local Storage
}
```

> Store the array as a property on the component

Very bad idea, the array needs to be passed from one component to another. **Services were made to share code.**

> Store the array in a file of static variables and grab when required

That file would keep growing, until you won't be able to maintain it. Think about separation of concern.

> Verdict:

Angular is an opinionated framework, go with whatever best practices has been mentioned by the Style Guide, if you don't want to suffer from Decision Fatigue!

Comment: TIL "Decision Fatigue": I like it.

Comment: Thanks, really useful response :)

Comment: @ShaneWatson You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in an external json file, and then retrieve the data in your controller. Just make sure to inject $http service when instantiating your controller.

```
$http.get('./data/countries.json').then(function(ret){
    $scope.countries = ret.data;
});
```

Comment: While this is true, is the (comparatively) huge overhead involved in the network request worth it, given the memory involved in storing this as a component property would only be a few hundred bytes?

Comment: @msanford If the data is static, as the OP says, then it will be cached by the client so it will actually perform better as it will only ever download once, as opposed to every time the user revisits the site.

Comment: @Archer "Only downloaded once" then why make an extra round trip for it, rather than inline it into the component?

Comment: @msanford That doesn't appear by magic - it still needs to download it if it's in a component, and a component is a lot less likely to be cached (I don't believe it will be).  Hence my comment "every time the user revisits the site".

Comment: @Archer I disagree with the premise that a component is less likely to be cached than any other static resource (given a good cache configuration), but I suppose that's also why I flagged this question as POB. :)

Comment: Er, this is _also_ a [tag:anguar.js] answer, but the question is about [tag:angular].